# HTML Search bar for each letter in string return picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all I would like to apologise if this question was worded badly. I do not use HTML often but found it very valuable for searching gifs for flashcards I create.

**Any experienced users please fix my question if need be!**

The problem:

I have a current page that has text that href to images. This is done for over 4000 characters.

[Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCcnI.png)

[Website View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihi5S.png)

When I press a Chinese character, it will open the gif corresponding to the character. Then I am able to copy and paste the gif for my flashcards. This is quite a long process if i'm making a flashcard which is a longer string, I need to search (Ctrl+F) and copy each character individually.

[Image opened from Hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOgYH.png)

What I would like to create is a search bar at the top of the webpage that allows me to create a longer string such as "你好吗" which will return the three corresponding gifs for each character under the search bar.

[Concept example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mDDK.png)

Thank you in advanced for any help!

```
UPDATE: This is my current code: https://pastebin.com/wsVbAmYG
```

~sasuke

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can be done in many ways with multiple frameworks.Please provide some code and ask more specific questions

Comment: @ItayGal Thank you for your reply. As I had mentioned, I'm not quite familiar with HTML and not quite sure how to approach this problem. I will upload my code now. https://pastebin.com/wsVbAmYG

Comment: Actually this is a JS question more than it's an HTML question. The main goal of stackoverflow is to help you overcome problems and deepen the understanding. You're asking for someone to do "your work"...

Comment: @ItayGal I didn't intend to make you angry with my question, I apologise. I'm just new to HTML/JS and would like to be pointed in the direction of how I could actually do this, I'm definitely fine with learning to do it myself :)

Comment: Not angry at all, I'm sorry if this was the impression. Usually a question like this will being closed. Just trying to explain what most users expect to see before they answer a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

With your code, I could see that the name of the image matched the unicode character. No more need for a table.

```js
const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {

  let html = '';

  const string = searchInput.value;
  for(let i = 0, iEnd = string.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
    const car = string.charAt(i);
    let hex = car.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    while (hex.length < 4) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    html += '<image src="images/' + hex + '.gif" alt="' + car + '" />';
  }

  resultContainer.innerHTML = html;

}, false);
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### OLD ANSWER

First, how the page is generated ? If you have a correspondence table, it might not be bad.

e.g. :
{
    '吗': 'images/4678.gif',
    '你': 'images/3579.gif'

}

If there is no correspondence table and it is a static page, you will have to create one (example in the code).

Then we get the chain and convert it.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const links = list.getElementsByTagName('a');

const correspondence = {};
for(let i = 0, iEnd = links.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
  const link = links[i];
  const car = link.innerHTML.trim();
  const image = link.getAttribute('href');
  correspondence[car] = image;
}

console.log(correspondence);


const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {

  let html = '';

  const string = searchInput.value;
  for(let i = 0, iEnd = string.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
    const car = string.charAt(i);

    if(correspondence[car]) {
      html += '<image src="' + correspondence[car] + '" alt="' + car + '" />';
    } else {
      html += ' ?' + car;
    }


  }

  resultContainer.innerHTML = html;

}, false);
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <a href="images/4556.gif">啊</a><br />
  <a href="images/4557.gif">爱</a><br />
  <a href="images/4558.gif">安</a><br />
  <a href="images/4559.gif">暗</a><br />
  <a href="images/4560.gif">按</a><br />
</div>

<input type="search" id="search" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see now that the line const image = link.getAttribute('href'); was the biggest issue I faced, not being able to get the link of the hyperlink.

Comment: I don't have your problem with your pastebin. What is the error message?
But finally, I updated my answer. You do not need a correspondence table.